# How can I extract a dictionary into Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to extract the following dictionary using a pandas data frame into Excel:

```
results = {'ZF_DTSPP': [735.0500558302846,678.5413714617252,772.0300704610595,722.254907241738,825.2955175305726], 'ZF_DTSPPG': [732.0500558302845,637.4786326591071,655.8462451037873,721.404907241738,821.8455175305724]}
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=results, index=[5, 2])
df = (df.T)
print(df)
df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')
```

Somehow I always receive following error:

> "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 2), indices imply (2, 2)".

What can I do? How do I need to adapt the index?

Is there a way to compare the different values of "ZF_DTSPP" and "ZF_DTSPPG" directly with python?

Comment: Why not simply: `pd.DataFrame(data=results)`? Index parameter is not the shape of your dict but the label of each row. Here, you said your dataframe has 2 rows named 5 and 2. Which is wrong because you have 5 rows.

Comment: The problem that occurs is that that your trying to assign only two numbers to the index of the dataframe. In total your dataframe has 5 rows (=indexes). Either provide 5 values, one for each row or leave out the part where you assign a value to the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` as shown in [pandas-from-dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), then your code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results)
```